# How to multiple a value by all items in a vector?

Tags: r

If I have a vector:

```
c(1.1, 1.2, 1.11, 1.21)
```

How do I apply the multiplication of each item to a value x where x is a number not a vector?

Expected calculation:

```
x * 1.1 * 1.2 * 1.11 * 1.21
```

Expected answer type: numeric

Comment: `x * Reduce(\`*\`, c(1.1, 1.2, 1.11, 1.21))`?

Comment: @camille One other note (since I see you got the backticks working in the comment) is that R will also accept quotes, `x * Reduce("*", ...)`

Answer (score 2):

We may use `prod` for `1.1 * 1.2 * 1.11 * 1.21`, in total giving, e.g.,

```
x <- 2
x * prod(c(1.1, 1.2, 1.11, 1.21))
# [1] 3.545784
```

Comment: or simply `prod(x, c(1.1, 1.2, 1.11, 1.21))`